# I need help programatically changing my combobox in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

```
int item = ComboBox.FindStringExact("Open"); 
    if (item >= 0) 
        ComboBox.SelectedItem = item;
```

I want to select the item in my combobox (programatically) to the one that says OPEN

My code doesn't work but I would appreciate any help

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is this Windows Forms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: is `item` >= 0?  Also, is the string case correct?

Comment: If you are using WinForms, please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you are saying it sounds like you want

```
ComboBox.SelectedIndex = item;
```

However, I would recommend sticking to using SelectedItem by using the following:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = "Open";  
//use the exact string that is used in the combobox.
```

Comment: Lol touche.  Didn't even notice I did that.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem` (I'm *assuming* `item >= 0` here).